# Is it safe to steam clean HVAC cooling fins?

Tags: hvac, maintenance

I am doing maintenance on my HVAC system, and I would like to know if the “fins” that are behind the AC filter can be cleaned via a household steamer.

I know more traditional HVAC systems can be washed down with a hose and some detergent, but mine is in a place where that method cannot be used (the unit is inside my condo). So I need a more “surgical” approach to cleaning it.

Anybody see an issue with this? Is the heat from a household steamer too much?

Comment: Seems likely to damage the coatings that are usually present, to prevent corrosion and promote water beading up and rolling off. In any case, check with the manufacturer before inventing a process that may not be suitable. A hose and detergent and a wet vacuum is a typical "surgical" approach.

Comment: Is the "steamer" hot? many so-called "steamers" make a luke-warm mist.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning coils starts with how dirty they are?
Coil design accessibility.
How thick is the coil, and what is the spacing of the fins. Seeing the coil behind the filter means it would be easy to clean. Vs unaccessable and having to remove it. Build up, can be brushed vacuumed, almost rolled up. Lint dust pollen.
Grease makes a mess.
Hand sprayer, mild detergent  water rinse.
Make sure drain stays clear.  It is very difficult to spray water all the way through.  Steam cleaning would be for decontamination. There is not enough volume to carry anything away with steam. Coil cleaning low pressure high volume

Comment: The question is about cooling fins, not coils.